# Get deleted column count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE FROM Disk
WHERE
Disk.Name = 'Recovery'
```

How can I get deleted column count in `sql-server`?

Comment: I want to know how many column deleted

Answer (score 2):

Right after the statement do:

```
set @num_deleted = @@rowcount
```

`@@rowcount` is a system variable that has the number of rows affected by the previous statement.  Read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

If you want to ask more about the rows than merely the number, you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to put them into a table variable.  You can then get the total number and other information about them.

Comment: please, can you show me syntax through my example code

Comment: @SamirH-evHemzeyev . . . Define the variable `@num_deleted`.  Add this right after your statement.  There is nothing confusing about the syntax.